# Automatic line-breaks in a long display-mode equation

Tags: equations, lyx, line-breaking

I have a long sequence of equalities and inequalities in a display-mode formula. Currently, this formula is longer than the page width.

Is there a way to tell LyX to automatically break the formula to two or more parts, at the equalities/inequalities symbols, according to the page width?

Here is an example formula:

```
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\log\log n\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\cdot f_{i}}  >  \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\log\log n\cdot\text{{Const}}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1/\log i)}  =  \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\log\log n\cdot\text{{Const}}\cdot(n/\log n)}  =  \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}  =  \infty$$
```

And an example output (for a certain page-width) where the formula is broken to 2 lines:

```
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\log\log n\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\cdot f_{i}}  >  \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\log\log n\cdot\text{{Const}}\cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}(1/\log i)} = $$
$$=  \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\log\log n\cdot\text{{Const}}\cdot(n/\log n)} =  \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{\log\log n} =  \infty$$
```

Comment: Do not use `$$...$$` but `\[...\]`. For automatic line breaking you have to read the manual of (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn)[breqn]. But I would not recommend that. Just do the line break manually as has been described in hundrets of post around here.

Comment: take a look at the multi-line display structures offered by `amsmath` (`texdoc amsmath`).  it's generally assumed that an author knows much more about the meaning of equations than any program, however well designed.  therefore, results should be better if the author decides the line breaks.

Comment: This is what I finally did - added line-breaks myself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the op in comments said that he had fixed (although not necessarily solved) the problem.